# Store files more than 4GB using IIS

Tags: iis

I have an application which creates the URL and sends a post request to server using IIS.
As per the microsoft library, maxallowedcontentlength is 4GB. But I want to store files more than 4GB, max size will be around 40GB.

Is there any approach to perform this task ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks. .

Comment: I wouldn't use HTTP protocol to upload such large files.

Comment: I agree to your point. But the server accepts only HTTP requests. I cannot change this. But I can modify the code if required.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split the file in parts,if you can

Comment: More detail would be great. A few words can answer _some_ questions, but not most. Also what would the OP do if he can't split them?

Comment: Yes, I also thought of this approach. But this approach requires changes in application and the server. Modifying the application is very difficult as many other layers are dependent on this application. I can modify the server, this will not be a problem.